# Collapsing the space between bars on a StackedBar100 in MSChart

Tags: c#, .net, charts, mschart

Essentially I have to show rows of bars on a stacked bar chart. There will be one for each question. Optionally there will be an extra bar or two for each question if there's a National score or a Competitor score is available.

My issue is one of presentation. I wish to place the bars central relative to the label for the question or remove gaps if one of the national or competitor scores isn't present.

Perhaps a picture will help:

[image: Charts]

I put together an example quickly (that generated the above picture) into an MVC project. These are the files:

**Index.cshtml**

```
<h2>Attempt 2</h2>
<img src="/Home/StackedBar100" />
<h2>Attempt 1</h2>
<img src="/Home/StackedBar100_FirstAttempt" />
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
<!-- language: c# -->
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    List<Color> colors = new List<Color>();
    string[] rows = new string[] { "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4" };
    string[] stackTypes = new string[] { "National", "Value", "Competitor" };
    Color[] stackColors = new Color[] { Color.White, Color.Green, Color.Orange };

    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        // Set up bands of colours for testing purposes.
        int diff = (255 - 20) / 10;
        for (int c = 10; c > 0; c--)
        {
            colors.Add(Color.FromArgb(0, (c * diff) + 10, 0));
        }

        base.Initialize(requestContext);
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult StackedBar100()
    {
        var chart = new Chart();
        var chartArea = new ChartArea("Default");
        chart.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);
        chart.Width = 640;
        chart.Height = 480;

        var r = new Random();
        for (int s = 0; s < stackTypes.Count(); s++)
        {
            var stack = stackTypes[s];
            var stackColor = stackColors[s];
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
                {
                    var series = new Series(stack + i.ToString());
                    series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedBar100;
                    series.Color = colors[i - 1];
                    series.BorderColor = stackColor;
                    series["StackedGroupName"] = stack;
                    series["DrawSideBySide"] = "true";
                    series.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
                    series.LabelForeColor = Color.White;
                    chart.Series.Add(series);
                }
            }
        }

        var dt = CreateData();

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            var question = row["Question"];
            var stack = row["Stack"];
            var hidden = Convert.ToBoolean(row["Hidden"]);
            var ks = "";
            for (int k = 1; k <= 10; k++)
            {
                ks = k.ToString();
                chart.Series[stack + ks].Points.AddXY(question, row[ks]);
                if (hidden)
                {
                    chart.Series[stack + ks].Points.Last().IsEmpty = true;
                }
                else if ((row[ks] as double?) < 3)
                {
                    chart.Series[stack + ks].Points.Last().IsValueShownAsLabel = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return ReturnChartAsImage(chart);
    }

    private DataTable CreateData()
    {
        var r = new Random();
        var dt = new DataTable("Chart Data");
        dt.Columns.Add("Question", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Stack", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Hidden", typeof(string));
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(i.ToString(), typeof(double));
        }

        foreach (var row in rows.OrderByDescending(rw => rw))
        {
            foreach (var stack in stackTypes)
            {
                if (
                  (stack == "Value") && row != "Q4" ||
                  (stack == "National" && (row == "Q2" || row == "Q4")) ||
                  (stack == "Competitor" && (row == "Q3" || row == "Q4")))
                {
                    var dr = dt.NewRow();
                    dr["Question"] = row;
                    dr["Hidden"] = false;
                    dr["Stack"] = stack;

                    for (int k = 1; k <= 10; k++)
                    {

                        dr[k.ToString()] = r.NextDouble() * 10;
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
                else
                {
                    var dr = dt.NewRow();
                    dr["Question"] = row;
                    dr["Stack"] = stack;
                    dr["Hidden"] = true;
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
            }
        }
        dt.WriteXml(@"c:\Users\chris_000\Desktop\1.xml");
        return dt;
    }

    public ActionResult StackedBar100_FirstAttempt()
    {
        var chart = new Chart();
        var chartArea = new ChartArea("Default");
        chart.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);
        chart.Width = 640;
        chart.Height = 480;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
        {
            var series = new Series("Series" + i.ToString());
            series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedBar100;
            series.Color = colors[(i - 1) % 10];

            if (i <= 10)
            {
                series["StackedGroupName"] = "Value";
            }
            else if (i > 10 && i <= 20)
            {
                series["StackedGroupName"] = "National";
                series.BorderColor = Color.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                series["StackedGroupName"] = "Competitor";
                series.BorderColor = Color.Orange;
            }

            chart.Series.Add(series);
        }

        var dt = CreateData_FirstAttempt();

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            var question = row["Question"];
            var group = row["Stack"];

            for (int k = 1; k <= 30; k++)
            {
                chart.Series["Series" + k.ToString()].Points.AddXY(question, row[k.ToString()]);
            }
        }

        return ReturnChartAsImage(chart);
    }

    private DataTable CreateData_FirstAttempt()
    {
        var r = new Random();
        var dt = new DataTable("Chart Data");
        dt.Columns.Add("Question", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Stack", typeof(string));  // Value, National, Competitor
        for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(i.ToString(), typeof(double));
        }

        foreach (var row in rows.OrderByDescending(rw => rw))
        {
            var dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Question"] = row;
            dr["Stack"] = "Score";

            for (int k = 1; k <= 30; k++)
            {
                if (k <= 10)
                {
                    if (row != "Q4") 
                    {
                        dr[k.ToString()] = r.NextDouble() * 100;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dr[k.ToString()] = DBNull.Value;
                    }
                }
                else if (k > 10 && k <= 20)
                {
                    if (row == "Q2" || row == "Q4")
                    {
                        dr[k.ToString()] = r.NextDouble();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dr[k.ToString()] = DBNull.Value;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (row == "Q3" || row == "Q4")
                    {
                        dr[k.ToString()] = r.NextDouble();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dr[k.ToString()] = DBNull.Value;
                    }
                }
            }

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        return dt;
    }

    private ActionResult ReturnChartAsImage(Chart chart)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        chart.SaveImage(ms, ChartImageFormat.Png);
        return File(ms.ToArray(), "image/png");
    }
}
```

That's a long example, but shows two different attempts at building multiple bars on a stacked chart. One using 30 columns, but splitting every 10 for each group. The second (more sensible) naming the stacks after the Value, National or Competitor they're supposed to represent.

So, in short, can I collapse the space occupied but the missing series/bars? Is it the way I'm feeding the data in perhaps?

Thanks.

Comment: The picture indeed would help. Most likely the series are not aligned because you don't add a point at each spot on each series. this is of the essence for all stacking to work without gaps..

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There was a picture, but it appears to have expired wherever it was hosted. I doubt I've got it still. I think we ended up going with a different way of presenting the data...